# Distinct not working properly

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct, having

I've wrote a query with `DISTINCT` but I still get duplicate records returned.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  `cuisine_types`.`id`, 
  `cuisine_types`.`name`, 
  `cuisine_types`.`image`, 
  (
    SELECT group_concat(`tagname` separator ', ') 
    FROM `cuisine_tags` 
    WHERE `cuisine_type` = `cuisine_types`.`id` 
  ) AS tags, 
  (
    3959 * acos( cos( radians(" . $dLat . ") ) * cos( radians( gps_lat ) ) * cos( radians( gps_lon ) - radians(" . $dLon . ") ) + sin( radians(" . $dLat . ") ) * sin( radians( gps_lat ) ) )
  ) AS distance 
FROM `company` 
LEFT JOIN `cuisine_types` 
ON 
    `company`.`cuisine_type_id` = `cuisine_types`.`id` 
HAVING 
    distance < " .$dMiles
```

When I try using the `GROUP BY` function my query isn't working properly.
When I use `GROUP BY` I place it above my `HAVING`:

```
GROUP BY `cuisine_types`.`name`
```

Examples:

When I use it with these values:

```
$dLat = '52.779716';
$dLon = '21.84803';
$iKm = '30';
```

It returns:

```
id = 1
name = Snackbar
image = 
tags = Patat, Snacks
distance = 17.4713944772963
```

When I use `$iKm` with 3000 it returns this row as well:

```
id = 1
name = Snackbar
image =
tags = Patat, Snacks
distance = 722.407714147792
```

So I get two records.
When I use this with groupby and `$iKm` = 30; It returns nothing. With a value of 3000 it returns one row. But I have one record with a distance of 17 miles so thats below 30.

Comment: I see no distinct in your query and what does not properly working mean?

Comment: I see no group by in your query and what does not working properly mean?

Comment: Sorry, I was trying things without distinct, for groupby check the top post.

Comment: Please give an example of the records returned that are not as you expect, and for better answers you should provide sample data that results in the error as wel.

Comment: @joe I added some examles, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix your problem, the issue was the distance calculation blocked the `GROUP BY` function. By putting the equation in the `HAVING` itself, the problem seemed to be fixed. Sorry I can't explain it in more detail.

```
SELECT 
            `cuisine_types`.`name`,
            `cuisine_types`.`id`,
             `cuisine_types`.`image`
            `c`.`gps_lat` as lat,
            `c`.`gps_lon` as lon,
            (SELECT group_concat(`tagname` separator ', ') FROM `cuisine_tags`  WHERE `cuisine_type`=`cuisine_types`.`id`) as tags FROM `company` as c  LEFT JOIN `cuisine_types` ON c.`cuisine_type_id`
= `cuisine_types`.`id` GROUP BY `cuisine_types`.`name` HAVING  ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(52.779716) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lon ) - radians(21.84803) ) + sin( radians(52.779716) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) < 2000;
```